# Printing Form in Landscape using PrintForm Function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, printing, printform

i have a question i am trying print the form in landscape so it can print all of the content of the form.

Here is the print preview look like it is cut.

[image]

I am using this code to print it and also use the landscape mode to true i search in google.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    Me.PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    Me.PrintForm1.Print()
End Sub
```

But it has the same result.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it's in landscape.  The margins look too thick though.

Comment: I replace the screenshot i cut it on paint thats why it looks like in landsacpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this along time ago from something I found on a Google search. It will give you a printersettings dialog where you can select landscape before printing. If memory serves, the Printform.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape is read only or has an issue. Can't remember, anyway, you will need to add a PageSetupDialog and a PrintDocument to the form. Then change your code to this:

```
    PageSetupDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    If PageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings = PageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings
        If PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
            PrintForm1.Print()
        End If
    End If
```

When you click your button1, you should be prompted with a page setup dialog where you can select landscape. Click OK and your form should print landscape.

I Guess if you don't want the Page Setup dialog, you could just have it print by setting the PageSetupDialog1's settings to Landscape.

```
    PageSetupDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintForm1.PrinterSettings = PageSetupDialog1.PrinterSettings
    If PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
        PrintForm1.Print()
    End If
```

Comment: Just a simple question. What is the printdocument1 ?? It says not declared thank you.

Comment: by default, it should be located in the printing section of your Toolbox pane. If you've already found the PageSetupDialog, it should have been in that same section.